# 404's on large request pages

Tags: linux, http-status-code-404

We just moved to a linux apache cpanel vps server. Some pages with large numbers of images are receiving many 404's per page load. Some images load while others result in a 404. different images get the errors every time. all images exist and are accessible. this was not a problem on the server we just moved from. I find in the apache error_log for each of these "client denied by server configuration".

I'm guessing there's a server setting somewhere limiting the amount of requests per period of time that will be accepted, but I can't find it anywhere.

Thank You, John

Answer (score 1):

Resolved! The Apache module called mod_evasive is turned on and is meant to prevent denial of service attacks by ratelimiting requests.

Thank you,
John